# Can we scale down/up OpenEBS Jiva replica count?

Tags: count, storage, replication, volume, openebs

I am using OpenEBS 0.6 version and I want to do scale down/up of Jiva replica count for my different applications? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

As of version 3.3.x, you can change the number of replicas by changing the `JivaVolumePolicy` as described in https://openebs.io/docs/3.3.x/user-guides/jiva/jiva-install#provisioning-jiva-volumes.

For example, in a default install of `openebs` in a microk8s cluster, you can change the value of `replicationFactor: 3` to desired value using the command:

```
kubectl edit JivaVolumePolicy openebs-jiva-default-policy -n openebs
```

Comment: Works OK (tested on microk8s), where `$ kubectl edit jvp -n openebs` can be used for short.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can scale OpenEBS Jiva replica count. Detailed steps are mentioned in the link below.
https://docs.openebs.io/docs/next/tasks_volumeprovisioning.html

Comment: This link is currently broken.